# How to keep a user-defined resolution on a Samsung (T220P) monitor?

Tags: display, resolution

I have a Samsung T220P monitor. Sometimes when I design websites, I need to temporarily switch to a low resolution. But the monitor won't let me keep it.

There is a message box shown on screen: `Not the optimum mode...Recommended: 1920 x 1200`. A few seconds later, the screen turns black, and I have to press the `Source` button to bring the screen back. This is really annoying because I have to press the button all the time to keep the low resolution.

It seems there's no such option in the menu to be configured. Does anyone have any experience with Samsung monitors? Does this have anything to do with monitor/video card driver or system/device configuration? How can I keep a preferred resolution?